# footer/element can't relative to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

CSS

```
.footer {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #292929;
}

.footer-inner {
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #111;
  color: #999;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="footer-inner">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12"> &copy; 2015 <a href="../../index.php">Japanex Rent-    A-Car Sdn Bhd</a>. </div>
    <!-- /span12 --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /row --> 
</div>
<!-- /container --> 
</div>
<!-- /footer-inner --> 
</div>
<!-- /footer -->
```

How can I keep my footer always at the bottom...because footer not always at the bottom of the page when the screen height is short...

Comment: check position:fixed and margin-top:0 what is this for?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
        </div><!-- #header -->

        <div id="content">
        </div><!-- #content -->

        <div id="footer">
        </div><!-- #footer -->

    </div><!-- #wrapper -->

html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:#ededed;
    padding:10px;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Please check the following URL.

http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/